# Python Discord Embedded Message Thumbnail Not Showing .jfif Images

Tags: discord, discord.py, jfif

I have a bot that sends embedded messages with thumbnails, but I noticed that .jfif images thumbnails are not being shown.

My question is does Discord support .jfif images on embedded messages thumbnails?

Answer (score 1):

The only images Discord supports are .png, .jpg, .jpeg.

If it's a local image file, you can try using [PIL](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

The code below might help.

```py
from PIL import Image
  
img_png = Image.open('test.jfif')
  
img_png.save('test.png')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The image is not local, and its type is not under my control... At least I know that it's Discord that is not supporting .jfif and it's not some other problem.

Comment: There might be a way where you can save the attachment as .jfif, and save it as a png. You should open a question about it, I could try.